# How to reset Heartbeat time in WordPress after AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i build real-time message like Facebook with Heartbeat feature in WordPress. But i have problem.

Structure like this:

**In database.**

```
-- message 1 
-- message 2
-- message 3
-- message 4
-- message 5
-- message 6
-- message n..
```

**In frontend show with Heartbeat:**

```
-- message 1
-- message 2
-- message 5
-- message 6
```

Where message 3,4? They are skipping because Heartbeat not reset the clock. So the function execute query with last message.

So, that problem will fixed if Heartbeat clock reset every AJAX success send. Maybe like this the logic.

```
-- Heartbeat in second 3 (after ajax)
-- Heartbeat in second 2 (after ajax)
-- Heartbeat in second 4 (after ajax)
```

Now how, to reset Heartbeat clock back to second 1 after ajax finish.

Answer (score 0):

> When the page loads, the client-side heartbeat code sets up an interval (called the “tick”) to run every 15-60 seconds.

**Server Side**

```
function wp_heartbeat_settings_3242( $settings ) {
    $settings['interval'] = 60; //Anything between 15-120
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'heartbeat_settings', 'wp_heartbeat_settings_3242' );
```

Additional reference: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-heartbeat-api-changing-the-pulse--wp-32462

**Client Side**

```
// 1 beat every 5 seconds for a maximum of two and half minutes
wp.heartbeat.interval( 'fast' );

// 1 beat every 60 seconds
wp.heartbeat.interval( 'slow' );

// 1 beat every 15 seconds
wp.heartbeat.interval( 'standard' );
```

But the real question here is why would you need "message 3,4". What i mean by that is i assume you are storing those message somewhere right? So basically every tick should be a check on the latest message with possibly associate value like "seen" implying the message was delivered. Also i don't believe you need to reset anything. You will never get the best real time effect unless you use WebSocket then store the conversation only has an archive.

But i could be wrong, hope it helps.

***Note: Maybe if you paste some code we could help further. :)***